# ALTER and UPDATE tables in SQL based on two criteria

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Edit 2:  I have updated the code to put in commas as suggested and I have changed the syntax to put it as table.column.

I have two tables in a SQL database (using Google's Cloud SQL if that matters).  The first table *pre2016q1* has columns *tag* and *adsh* (and several others).  I want to add columns, and then populate those columns with values from another table *num2016q1*, which also has the columns *tag* and *adsh* when the values are equal in both tables.

Note: These are large tables with > 2MM rows each.

Edit1:  I'm asking before I run because it took a long time to get the DB in its current state, and I don't want to screw the whole thing up.

Question 1: Will the code below perform the operation described above?

Question 2: If there is no equivalent to *tag* and *adsh* will the records be left blank?

Question 3:  Is having a column named *value* going to cause any issues or should I rename that beforehand?

Question 4: Does the size of the table matter at all in the time the operation will take?  (I only ask because I need to do this operation 16 times).

```
ALTER TABLE pre2016q1
ADD
    version VARCHAR(20),
    ddate INTEGER,
    qtrs INTEGER,
    uom VARCHAR(20),
    value NUMERIC(28,4),
    footnote VARCHAR(512);

UPDATE 
    pre2016q1
SET 
    pre2016q1.ddate = num2016q1.ddate, 
    pre2016q1.qtrs = num2016q1.qtrs, 
    pre2016q1.uom = num2016q1.uom, 
    pre2016q1.value = num2016q1.value, 
    pre2016q1.footnote = num2016q1.footnote
WHERE
    adsh.pre2016q1 = adsh.num2016q1 AND tag.pre2016q1 = tag.num2016q1;
```

Comment: You need to join num2016q1 and it is important to know what flavour of SQL Googles Cloud Sql is because the update/join syntax differs between MYSQL and SQL-SERVER.

Comment: The alter table syntax is incorrect and the set statement is incorrect.(MYSQL)

Comment: Could you help me out with what is incorrect, especially on the SET part?

Comment: add a comma to separate each set statement. Is adsh a schema? and pre2016q1 and pre2016q1 tables?

Comment: adsh is a column in both tables.  Tables are pre2016q1 and num2016q1

Comment: added my answer. check. Updated the answer to answer all your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:** I'd use something like this

```sql
ALTER TABLE pre2016q1
ADD
    version VARCHAR(20)
    ,ddate INTEGER
    ,qtrs INTEGER
    ,uom VARCHAR(20)
    ,value NUMERIC(28,4)
    ,footnote VARCHAR(512)
GO

UPDATE 
    pre
SET 
    pre.version = num.version
    ,pre.ddate = num.ddate
    ,pre.qtrs = num.qtrs
    ,pre.uom = num.uom
    ,pre.value = num.value
    ,pre.footnote = num.footnote
FROM pre2016q1 pre
INNER JOIN num2016q1 num
  ON pre.adsh = num.adsh AND pre.tag = num.tag
```

**Question 2** the records will be blank.

**Question 3** Good if you could rename it to something else.

**Question 4** The amount of records does have an impact but it will not take a great deal of time

Comment: Cool.  couple of questions:
1) What is the FROM pre2016q1 pre doing?
2) what's the deal with pre vs. pre2016q1 and num vs. num2016q1?

Comment: 1) It's joining the two tables. You can interchange the tables names in FROM and INNER JOIN but make sure the alias pre is the one that goes into the UPDATE. 2) I am just using an alias to make the term short. You can use the table name itself if you want. no issues.

Answer (score 0):

the update seems wrong firts the tablename and after the field name

```
UPDATE 
    pre2016q1
SET 
    pre2016q1.version =num2016q1.version
    pre2016q1.ddate = num2016q1.ddate.num2016q1
    pre2016q1.qtrs = num2016q1.qtrs
    pre2016q1.uom = num2016q1.uom
    pre2016q1.value = num2016q1.value
    pre2016q1.footnote = num2016q1.footnote
WHERE
    pre2016q1.adsh = num2016q1.adsh AND pre2016q1.tag = num2016q1.tag
```